# Unable to get Flow Formula References In Salesforce

Tags: salesforce-id, visual-flows

[image: Flow Screenshot]

Trying to replicate Condition 1 in by adding new condition but couldn't see any reference after myVariable.Current.CreatedyBy.

Comment: do you mean `myVariable_Current` ?

Comment: I am trying to add "myVariable_Curent.CreatedBy.UserRole.Name" but I am not getting any results after "myVariable_Curent.CreatedBy...."

Comment: Type it in manually rather than using the prompted options